# Select all the elements with the same class, with some having two classes

Tags: jquery, html, class, jquery-selectors

I try to select all the elements having the same class, and do css() on them.

It works when the elements have one class, but when they have two classes these ones are not selected.

My elements :

```js
var ville; 


$("#enigme1_answers td").hover(

 function() {
  
  ville = $(this).html().toLowerCase();  
  
  $( "[class=" + ville + "]" ).css("background-color", "red");
  
  
 }, function() {
  
  $( "[class=" + ville + "]" ).css("background-color", "#2a3843");
 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
 <td class="oslo"> O </td>
 <td class="oslo lecaire"> L </td>
 <td class="oslo viennes"> S </td>
 <td class="oslo gaborone"> O </td>
 <td class=erevan"> V </td>
 <td class="berlin"> N </td>
 <td class="rome"> E </td>
 <td class="athenes"> S </td>
 <td class="athenes"> E </td>
 <td class="athenes"> N </td>
 <td class="athenes"> E </td>
 <td class="athenes"> H </td>
 <td class="athenes"> T </td>
 <td class="athenes damas"> A </td>
</tr>
```

I do with the method $("[class=myclass]").
The elements with one class like Athenes (except the A) are correctly modified, but not those with two classes. I want the elements modified when one of their class is selected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".classname")
```

Instead of:

```
$("[class=classname]")
```

### Why

`[class=classname]` compares the entire class attribute, so you are getting both classes, oslos and lecaire.  Whereas, `$(".classname")` will get all HTML objects with the class.

### Applying it to your code

```js
$("#enigme1_answers").hover(function() { 
  $(this).find("td.oslo").css("background-color", "red");
}, function() {
  $(this).find("td.oslo").css("background-color", "#2a3843")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr id="enigme1_answers">
  <td class="oslo"> O </td>
  <td class="oslo lecaire"> L </td>
  <td class="oslo viennes"> S </td>
  <td class="oslo gaborone"> O </td>
  <td class="erevan"> V </td>
  <td class="berlin"> N </td>
  <td class="rome"> E </td>
  <td class="athenes"> S </td>
  <td class="athenes"> E </td>
  <td class="athenes"> N </td>
  <td class="athenes"> E </td>
  <td class="athenes"> H </td>
  <td class="athenes"> T </td>
  <td class="athenes damas"> A </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I did it first, but it did the css() action just for the first letter having the class, not all of them

Comment: Look under section applying to your code, updated the post.  I noticed that there was no `table` around your `<tr>` which makes `tr` undetectable.

Comment: Hey, if you could mark my answer as solution/upvote, that'd help a lot.  And just ask me if you have any more questions.  I'm going to call it a night, but I'll be back on tomorrow.

Comment: And check with the .find, anf if it's correct you have the correct answer don't worry

Comment: Yeah, if you ever get curious, look into css selectors.  jQuery uses those when finding elements.